# SwiftUI sheet within sheet won't show an alert

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

In my app, I am presenting a sheet within a sheet. On this second sheet, alerts will not function. Is my only solution to change the structure of my app, maybe to propagate the error up?

This can be seen in a SwiftUI preview with something like:

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true), content: {
        Text("World")
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true), content: {
                Text("3rd screen")
                    .alert("Error", isPresented: .constant(true), actions: {})
            })
    })
```

If you move the alert up to the "World" text, the alert appears:

```swift
Text("Hello")
    .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true), content: {
        Text("World")
            .alert("Error", isPresented: .constant(true), actions: {})
            .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true), content: {
                Text("3rd screen")
            })
    })
```

Comment: Why are you using `.constant(true)` everywhere? You are trying to present the alert even before the second sheet is shown. How about adding a new `@State` to control the alert so that you can wait a little before showing the alert?

Comment: As I said, the above was just example code to show the problem in a SwiftUI preview. In the actual code I do use view models and state variables, and the issue is the same as seen in the example preview code above.